# E: Unable to locate package python3-eyeD3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, eyed3

is *eyed3* is not available for python 3 on ubuntu?

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-eyeD3
```

Getting error

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done E: Unable to locate package python3-eyeD3
```

Comment: Try `sudo -H pip3 install eyeD`

Comment: after using this   ,    Collecting eyeD
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement eyeD (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for eyeD

Comment: Sorry for typo `pip3 search eyeD3` yeilds eyeD3 0.8.8 . Try `sudo -H pip3 install eyeD3`